# Query and match data in multiple tabs of 1 Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have two tabs that list names along with other data. I would like to query "Leads Weekly" A:E and have that data pull the value of column E where A matches C on another Sheet. ?

I've tried query formulas : =QUERY('Leads weekly'!A:E, "Select E where A contains 'MELISSA SURO'")

which works, but I'm looking for something scalable, I have over 500 names I would have to type in.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=QUERY('Leads weekly'!A:E, 
 "select E where A matches '"&TEXTJOIN("|", 1, Sheet!C:C)&"'", )
```

Comment: Perfect! I've been trying to figure this out for hours! Life saver!!!!!!!